# Generating a .lib file when using MinGW

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, .lib

I am making a C++ project, and want to use ViennaRNA (https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#download) in it. I am currently working on Windows 10. I downloaded the source code, and followed the steps to setup ViennaRNA. Basically, I extracted the tar.gz, used MinGW to run ./configure and then ran make and make install from a regular terminal. I get .c, .h, .la, .lo nd .o files in the src folder, but no .lib. The documentation for ViennaRNA just says that I can compile from source code on Linux, Mac or Windows and I should get a RNAlib. There is also a RNAlib2.pc file that was generated at the root folder, but that doesn't work if I try to include it in my external library dependencies as I would do with a .lib file. Did I skip a step? Or do I have to do something extra since I am on Windows, and not Linux?

Any help or pointers are appreciated, as I am fairly new with generating and integrating compiled libraries

Comment: The `.a` file is a library.

Comment: My mistake, there are no .a files, only .c, .h, .la, .lo and .o files. Just updated the questions

Comment: Isn't the .la a library ? Normally it's .a but some people name them differently. We would need to have a look at the makefile to say. However, note that MinGW .a and VS .lib are interoperable only in C, not C++ (due to different name mangling).

Comment: @QuentinC I believe .la is a library. However, whatever I read says that .la, .a, .o, etc. are all for linux. I am working from windows, and my limited knowledge is that I need to include a .lib file and the .h in the dependencies to include the library in my own project. As for the different name mangling, I read on another question that using extern c sometimes allows to make the 2 compatible. I do have access to a linux machine, but my end goal is to integrate 3 different libraries into a extern c dll and create a website with dotnet, and that works on windows.

Comment: No, .o and .a aren't linux-specific. .o stands for object code and .a for archive. AS far as I know, object code is architecture/CPU-specific but not OS-specific. When using MinGW as a compiler, you always link with .a libraries, on windows as well as on linux. Have you tried to rename your .la in .a and link with it ?

Comment: @QuentinC I actually was able to generate a .a, but adding it in the projects still gives me unrecognized object. I tried changing the extension as well but to no avail. I do have a Linux machine and I am now trying to link it correctly, but vscode doesn't seem to give the same options as visual studio. I created another question for it :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77636770/properly-linking-a-static-library-in-vscode-with-terminal-command