# Properly linking a static library in vscode with terminal command

Tags: c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, gcc, lib

I downloaded the source code of ViennaRNA (https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#download) on an Ubuntu system and followed the steps (./configure, make and sudo make install). It generated a static library (libRNA), amongst others. I checked my /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include and the library and header files are in their appropriate folders. I then created a simple C program (one .c file with a main function), that calls one of the functions from the static library. When I try to run my program through the play button, it give me the undefined reference to 'function in static library' error.

Error example: `` /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccP1SOcg.o: in function `main': MyCProgram.c:(text+0x30): undefined reference to `vrna_fold_comp ``

If try to compile and link it in the vscode terminal by using gcc and specifying my library (`gcc -o MyCProgram MyCProgram.c -lRNA`), it gives me a bunch of undefined reference to 'XYZ' related to the files in the original downloaded source code path (where I had originally run ./configure, make and sudo install).

Error example:
`` /usr/bin/ld: /home/Documents/ViennaRNA-2.6.4/src/../../src/ViennaRNA/loops/internal.h:573: undefined reference to `log' ``

How do I make it so that the linker can find my function? In Visual Studios on Windows, I would add the folder in the linker options, but it seems that I can't do that on vscode.

Comment: Option -lXYZ is correct, but will look for a file named libXYZ.a. Rename in consequence if needed. Use -L with capital L to specify a lib directory.